# SQL Server differential duration of multiple inserts

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, insert

I'm running web application and importing huge amount of data to the sql server database every day. Unfortunately I've experienced server fault (hard drive broke down) and I had to reinstall SQL Server and other apps on a new machine.
My problem is that after setting the system up from scratch importing data to database started  to be very long-drawn. New machine is much faster than older one (64GB RAM, 8 threads...), and all other actions performed on the application are executed in a moment.

Data import looks like this:

1. Reading XML file
2. Iterating through each row and inserting it to the database (no bulk insert, no transactions - just clean insert command)

Before server fault processing 200 000 rows took about 2 minutes, now its about 20 minutes :(
I think i've tried everything, here is a screenshot from SQL Profiler:

http://content.screencast.com/users/czyzas/folders/Jing/media/50bc21c1-1e98-478e-88d1-0751f447b619/2013-04-24_1932.png

All rows in the table are insert statements. As you can see, duration varies from 7 to 120, so i think that here is the problem.
Has anybody got a clue what might be the reason??

Thanks in advance! :)

p.s. There are two hard drives in the system (RAID), SQL Server 2008 R2

EDIT:
Database was created from a backup

Table schema looks like this:

```
create table [tempUpload].[Import_0016704] (
ROWNO int identity primary key,
[TheDate] nvarchar(10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
[Campaign] nvarchar(35) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
[AdGroup] nvarchar(7) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
[Domain] nvarchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
[Impressions] nvarchar(5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
[Cost] nvarchar(8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
[ConversionsOnePerClick] nvarchar(1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
[Clicks] nvarchar(2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
[ClientId] nvarchar(10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
)
```

And single insert looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert into  [tempUpload].[Import_0016704] ([TheDate],[Campaign],    [AdGroup],[Domain],[Impressions],[Cost],[ConversionsOnePerClick],[Clicks],[ClientId])     
select 
@v_165,@v_166,@v_167,@v_168,@v_172,@v_174,@v_176,@v_173,@v_177',
N'@v_165 nvarchar(20), @v_166 nvarchar(70),@v_167 nvarchar(14),@v_168 nvarchar(100),@v_172 nvarchar(10),@v_174 nvarchar(16),@v_176 nvarchar(2),@v_173 nvarchar(4),@v_177 nvarchar(20)',
@v_165=N'2013-04-07',@v_166=N'Tematy',
@v_167=N'120x600',
@v_168=N'gallery.com',
@v_172=N'21',
@v_174=N'0',
@v_176=N'0',
@v_173=N'0',
@v_177=N'243'
```

Just give me a sign if you need more details on this.

Comment: Are you saying that you recreated your database by hand, instead of just restoring from a backup?

Comment: 30ms is very long for a single row insert and points to disk IO problems. Looks like 3 disk seeks just for one insert. Anyway, this question cannot be answered without a lot more detail about schema, data and plans. Right now, the question reads a little like "I have a lot of insert statements. It is taking too long. Why?" Nobody can answer that.

Comment: I've edited a post with new details, just let me know if you need something else :)

Comment: Performance is what SSIS does well.  You have hundreds of thousands of rows, it's taking too long, you might need SSIS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but before server fault there was no Integration Services implemented in my project. There have to be something else affecting my performance.

Comment: Ok, are there indexes? Can you post the actual execution plan of an insert? Preferably one of the slower ones if you can find one.